# Bind9 on Debian : nslookup point on localhost not my ip server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, subdomain, nameserver, reverse-dns

i have just install bind9 on Debian.

I think i haven't configured not everything because i still have a problem with the DNS and the propagation. I think the problem is say by `nslookup` :

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53
```

The command :

```
root@ks3309528:~# nslookup stats.yt
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   stats.yt
Address: 5.135.160.63

root@ks3309528:~# nslookup cakebox.stats.yt
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   cakebox.stats.yt
Address: 5.135.130.63
```

Maybe it's my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.186.33.99
search ovh.net
```

My name.conf.options :

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { ::1; };
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1;};
};
```

an my `db.statsyt`

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ks3309528.kimsufi.com. root.stats.yt. (
        2014012514      ;serial
        3600            ;refresh
        600             ;retry
        2419200         ;expire
        600)            ;minimum
@        IN NS     ks3309528.kimsufi.com.
@        IN NS     ns.kimsufi.com.
stats.yt.            IN A      5.135.160.63
www                  IN CNAME  stats.yt.
cakebox              IN A      5.135.130.63
```

And `db.statsyt.inv`

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ks3309528.kimsufi.com. root.stats.yt. ( 2014012501 3600 600 2419200 600)
@        NS     ks3309528.kimsufi.com.

63      IN PTR  stats.yt.
```

So the problem is the ip of the server and adress i think.

If i do https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/cakebox.stats.yt

It's ok, but why i  can't acces to [cakebox.stats.yt](http://cakebox.stats.yt) ?

Or the problem is from apache ?

Comment: So, is cakebox.stats.yt supposed to be on a different IP than stats.yt? Typo in your zone? 130 != 160.

Comment: f***ck ! thx, i correct this error, know i need to wait for the dns ? Also did my `resolv.conf` is good ?

Comment: Yes. And otherwise it looks alright. Will post it as an answer.

Comment: ok, so when i can acces to my cakebox.stats.yt (wait dns) i post your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your zone:

```
stats.yt.            IN A      5.135.**160**.63
www                  IN CNAME  stats.yt.
cakebox              IN A      5.135.**130**.63
```

Hint: use a CNAME to avoid this type of problem like you've did with `www`.